# Is it possible to change data type inside a SimpleXMLElement object with PHP?

Tags: php, object, simplexml, type-conversion

I have this object

```
$data = simplexml_load_string('<xml><admin>0</admin></xml>');
```

where $data->admin = "0" `(string)`. So with a string 0, the following would always return true

```
if($data->admin) {
    echo 'is admin';
}
```

By casting the variable, this would work correctly

```
if((int)$data->admin) {
    echo 'is admin';
}
```

But I'm still wondering if it's possible to change the data type inside the object (like doing so inside an array) so I don't have to do type casting.

Answer (score 0):

Not with SimpleXML.  What you can do is use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.  Using SimpleXML isn't recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If string is '0' it will return false. If you cast it to int it will still return false. ) And at the end logical expressions are cast to boolean. So what you trying to do is useless)

Comment: have you tested? I just did! `$data->admin` returns a string 0, and `if($data->admin)` returns **true** no matter the value is 1 or 0!

Comment: Ok I will test it now)) But its unbelievable.

Comment: Ok, you are right) but its because its considered as object. Not as string. Try this: if($data->admin!=0)

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do so in PHP, instead of typecast it you could just try this solution

```
if ($data->admin != 0){ 
    //is admin
}
```

Comment: yes, that's the way I did before type casting. it seems that I have to live with it or learn some DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this) Though I don't think its good way) The best here is compare again zero and not to make typecasting. If you want typecasting you can do following. But its not good practice to make 3 operations instead of 1 )

```
$data = simplexml_load_string('<xml><admin>0</admin></xml>');
if(strip_tags($data->admin->asXML()))
{
//is admin
}
```